# Atomic Map Access and Modification in C++ without Locks

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, stdatomic

I'm trying to achieve atomic access and modification to a map in C++ without using locks. I have a single writer thread, and I want to ensure that the map can be safely accessed and modified without the need for locks.

I came across the blue-green pattern mentioned in Arthur O'Dwyer's CppCon talk (https://youtu.be/F6Ipn7gCOsY?t=3466), which seems like a promising approach. However, I'm facing some issues with my implementation, and I would appreciate some guidance from the community.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

struct Config {
    using ConfigMap = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

    std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<const ConfigMap>> g_config;

    void set(const std::string& key, const std::string& value) {
        std::shared_ptr<const ConfigMap> blue = g_config.load();
        std::shared_ptr<ConfigMap> green = std::make_shared<ConfigMap>(*blue);
        std::cerr << "This is not printing to the console" << std::endl << std::flush;
        (*green)[key] = value;
        g_config.store(std::move(green));
    }

    std::optional<std::string> get(const std::string& key) {
        std::shared_ptr<const ConfigMap> blue = g_config.load();
        auto valueIter = blue->find(key);
        if (valueIter != blue->end()) {
            return valueIter->second;
        }
        return std::nullopt; // Indicates that the value was not found
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Main starting" << std::endl;

    Config config;
    std::string key = "default.hostname";
    std::string value = "example.com";

    std::thread setThread([&config, &key, &value]() {
        config.set(key, value);
        std::cout << "Set thread completed" << std::endl;
    });

    setThread.join();

    std::optional<std::string> hostnameOpt = config.get("default.hostname");
    if (hostnameOpt) {
        std::string hostname = *hostnameOpt;
        std::cout << "Default Hostname: " << hostname << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Default Hostname not set" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the message "This is not printing to the console" inside the set function is not being displayed. It seems like the code execution is not reaching that point. However, the program compiles successfully without any errors.

I suspect there might be a problem with my usage of atomic variables or shared pointers. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and achieve atomic map access and modification without using locks.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: [Executed with Asan](https://godbolt.org/z/WrGqqoao7) / [Executed with Tsan](https://godbolt.org/z/5Ezqb8bof)

Comment: Unrelated: `std::endl << std::flush;` - the `flush` after `endl` is redundant. `endl` flushes too.

Comment: thankyou @TedLyngmo ! https://godbolt.org/z/ohfeTbj4b
so the error seems to be happening because i havent initialized the shared_ptr while Config is constructed right ? can you please check the new compiler explorer link it seems to work. can you please verify

Comment: Why use probably one of the most bloated and inefficient container (`map`) and not a simple sequence like `vector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g_config` is never initialised so your call to `std::make_shared<ConfigMap>(*blue)` has undefined behaviour as `blue` is a null pointer.

Also note that (at least in libstdc++, and I'd be surprised if other implementations are different) `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<const ConfigMap>>` isn't lockfree so you're using a mutex anyway and a `set` will not only have to completely copy the map it'll also lock the mutex twice giving much worse performance than if you'd just locked the map once.

Note that whilst fixing this makes your code "work" it really isn't thread safe. Imagine two threads executing `set` at the same time:

1. Thread A loads `g_config` into `blue` and copies into its `green`
2. Thread B loads `g_config` into `blue` and copies into its `green`
3. Thread A sets the key 'A' into its `green`
4. Thread B sets the key 'B' into its `green`
5. Thread A stores its `green` into `g_config`
6. Thread B stores its `green` into `g_config` discarding the changes made by thread A.

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G6vjdc5GT)

You could solve this problem with a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) loop but you might find it easier and more performant to just use a mutex:

```
    void set(const std::string& key, const std::string& value) {
        std::shared_ptr<const ConfigMap> blue = g_config.load();
        while (true)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<ConfigMap> green = std::make_shared<ConfigMap>(*blue);
            (*green)[key] = value;
            if (g_config.compare_exchange_weak(blue, std::move(green)))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Go49a9hnE)

Comment: yep i benchmarked it mutex worked better. thankyou for this detailed solution

Comment: std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<const ConfigMap>>
can you please tell me why it isnt lock free ?

Comment: regarding CAS loop i dont need it because i am only having 1 writer thread

Comment: generally only trivial types with size less than the size of the atomic instructions available on your CPU (e.g. 64-bit). A `shared_ptr` isn't POD, and is likely too big (typically it contains two pointers)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCgu8YNLYME

Comment: Skimming generated assembly, `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` looks lock-free to me on x86-64 and arm64.  Most 64-bit architectures have at least a 128-bit atomic compare-exchange exactly for things like this.

Comment: @NateEldredge watch the youtube video it explains why its so difficult to implement, libstdc++ and msvc didn't bother and are now stuck with locking implementations and can't change it without breaking ABI. [libstdc++ states it's not lock-free and clang hasn't implemented it](https://godbolt.org/z/ehEh7hhrM). [MSVC states it's not lock free](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/c8d1efb6d504f6392acf8f6d01fd703f7c8826c0/stl/inc/memory#L3911)

Comment: @NateEldredge looks like both libstdc++ and msvc use spinning an atomic counter rather than a mutex but that doesn't count as lockfree

Comment: @AlanBirtles Wasting CPU time instead of giving time to other threads, potentially blocking other threads if real time priorities are used, cannot "count" as lockfree as it is indeed locking.